# Build a pipeline with kafka connect using jdbc connectors for sqlite

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am new to kafka connect, trying to build a pipeline to get data from sqlite to kafka topic.

Comment: Despite being new, what attempts have you made?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your sqlite DB is at `/tmp/test.db` then use this config:

```
{
  "name": "jdbc-source",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlite:/tmp/test.db",
    "mode": "incrementing",
    "incrementing.column.name": "id",
    "topic.prefix": "test-sqlite-jdbc-",
    "name": "jdbc-source"
  }
}
```

For more details, see :

- https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/source_connector.html#quick-start
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/